# Mongo Atlas DB into Rstudio

Tags: r, mongodb

I am trying to make a connection from Mongo Atlas into R but nothing seems to work I have tried mongolite and RMongo, is there any good solution to make a connection with my atlas mongodb into R studio.

Comment: Please show the code you tried and the error messages or problems.

Answer (score 4):

```
library(mongolite) 
mongo<- mongo(collection = "nameofcollection", db = "nameofdb", url = "mongodb://usr:pass@cluster0-shard-00-00-h8acf.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-12ucd.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-haucd.mongodb.net:27017/dbname?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin", verbose = TRUE)
```

You need change nameofcollection, nameofdb and dbname for your user password and dbname of atlas.

Change cluster url for yours cluster (atlas give you a url)

Answer (score 2):

1) Go to Atlas (https://cloud.mongodb.com)

2) Go to your cluster, and click on the Connect button

3) Select "Connect your application"

4) In there, you'll see a Connection String, which will allow you to see the host name/URL for the cluster

You can then use the following R code in order to connect to your Atlas MongoDB cluster:

```
library(mongolite)

mongo_db_user <- "myuseranme"
mongo_db_password <- "mypassword"
mongo_database <- "mydatabase"
mongo_collection <- "mycollection"
mongo_clustername <- "cluster123-abc.mongodb.net"

# the following is the connection string for an Atlas online MongoDB cluster
url_path = sprintf("mongodb+srv://%s:%s@%s/admin",
                   mongo_db_user, mongo_db_password, mongo_clustername)

mongo_db <- mongo(collection = mongo_collection, db = mongo_database, url = url_path, verbose = TRUE)

data <- data.frame(Date = c("2020-04-21", "2020-04-20"), Returns = c(0.05, 0.02) )
mongo_db$insert(data)

rm(mongo_db) # disconnection
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this for a while. Make sure to run - `brew install` openssl in terminal to set up the ssl connection! Then it worked fine for me. Cheers